# Computing long expression in ArcGIS field calculator?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, fields-attributes

I am trying to compute the following expression with the Field Calculator of ArcMap. The input table values are around the size of this value: 562643580,7843, and the field name (the field of destination) is: double, precision=20, scale=20:

`([Sum_Pri_17]*0.0669)+(([Sum_Pri_18]-[Sum_Pri_17])*0.0551)+(([Sum_Pri_19]-[Sum_Pri_18])*0.0306)`

The destination field should therefore not be too short. When doing the calculation, no result is computed and no error appears either.

I thought the expression was too long, so I tried to compute the following:

`[Sum_Pri_17]*0.0669`

The calculation's result was the same: no result is computed and no error appears either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You say your input values are similar to "562643580,7843". well you have a comma not a decimal point so the entire value would be treat as a text that's probably why you are getting nothing?